# data types and structs in C#

Tags: c#, types, struct

I've been using `"Int32", "String", and "Boolean"` instead of `"int", "string", "bool"` in C# for a while now, but I don't know why.  Why does this matter?  Which is "better"?  What's the difference?

I have used `Int32`? because it is nullable in my ORM for my database, so there is that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference to the compiled code; `int` is synonymous with `System.Int32` and `string` is synonymous with `System.String`.

However, using `int` and `string` etc. is more idiomatic.

Comment: There's no difference. `String` and `Int32` are the actual type names in the .NET Framework. `string` and `int` are aliases for them defined by the C# language (probably to make it more like C/C++).

Comment: It's a product of the .NET Common Type System - also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's largely a stylistic issue -- the builtin type names like `int` are [formally defined as aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691144%28VS.71%29.aspx) for standard library types like `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 0):

'int' is simply an alias for "Int32".  However, I have never seen any code that uses the aliased classes instead of the alias in C#.  If I wanted to make damn sure that the int I was using was 32 bits I would use Int32, but I don't see a reason for using the more verbose "Boolean" instead of the standard alias, "bool".

Comment: It's so OCD for me it comes down to colors and case in Visual Studio.  I know, it's insane.

Comment: @Ed: Even if you did want to make damn sure that an int was 32 bits then you could still use `int` rather than `Int32`. It's guaranteed in the C# and CLI specs. It won't change.

Comment: Luke: For people who don't know the spec by heart of in code where numerout different bit-nesses of integers are used I think it can actually make a readability difference.

Comment: `Int32` can be useful when dealing with interop and binary issues. I used it e.g. when writing a binary format parser, just because it looked more consistent in the mix with Int16, UInt16 etc.

Comment: You don't need to know a spec by heart, to be honest - virtually every "C# for Dummies" kind of book I've seen has a table of primitive types with their keywords and ranges right in the first chapter.

Answer (score 0):

i would stick to `int, string, bool` just incase i decide to port the code or part of the code to c/c++, it just makes it a little easier. also you would know that everybody knows what an `int` is bu they might not know that it's the same as `Int32`. even though they are basically the same i'd stick to `int, string, bool`.